# populating a select box from php mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to populate a selection box (dropdown) from a mysql table in php, but I get blank results, Can someone look in my code and tell me what is wrong?

I need to populate the select with the dates available from my sql query, so they show up as seletion options....

```
<?php

echo JText::_('Please select the date:');

$database= &JFactory::getDBO();
$database->setQuery('SELECT training_id,training,trainingDate FROM training');
$result = $database->loadObjectList();

echo '<select name="whatever">';
foreach ($result as $row) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row->training_id.'" />';

}
echo '</select>';

?>
```

Comment: What is `JText`/`JFactory`? What is the actual output (i.e. the rendered HTML)?

Comment: Additionally... what do you get when you `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: this one brings up the results: foreach ($result as $key=>$value){

 

            $selHtml = $selected == $value->id? 'selected="selected"' : '';

            echo "<option $selHtml value=".$value->training_id.">".$value->training.", ".$value->trainingDate."</option>";

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<option value="'.$row->training_id.'">'.$row->trainingDate.'</option>';
```

If that doesn't work then your $row->training_id isn't set and so you'll need to debug that (e.g. doing a print_r($row) just before that line to see what is inside the $row object)

Comment: Cool that brings up the ids, how do I bring up the traininDate instead

Comment: Ok I changed the training_id to trainingDate and worked , thanks.. now the rest....

Comment: Ok thanks  a lot , I ll be asking a new question shortly on how to insert this value. thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

You assign an option value, but you don't provide human-readable option text:

```
echo '<select name="whatever">';
foreach ($result as $row) {
                                                 <!-- here we go -->
   echo '<option value="'.$row->training_id.'">'.$row->training.'</option>'; // always close options!!!

}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: it's my typo. should be `training`. fixed

Comment: you meant training right, well can you verify the sintax here, it seems to be error:echo '<option value="'.$row->training_id.'" />'.$row->training.'</option>'; // always close options!!!

Comment: Sorry I am not using a debugger is just a joomla plugin called, sourcer

Comment: You don't need a debugger, just turn `error_reporting` on (on development version) or tell php to log errors somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
```

instead of this:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
```